# Javascript subtracting epoch times

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a little snippet of code for which is below to take the elapsed time between the variable QCC and the current time  the QCC variable is always equal to an epoch time such as 1406203032  what I want is the get Last check to equal like 1000 for example where 1000 is 1000 seconds of elapsed time and then I can do some maths to it to convert it to minuets and then do want with that

```
LastCheck =   Date.now() - QCC  ;
```

Comment: More like an answer than a question.  What's wrong with what you've done there?

Comment: when i log the results of LastCheck im getting large nummbers such as 1404798710689 i would be expecting numbers within the 10000 no?

Comment: I don't think so, 10000 is 10 seconds.  If you're getting results that large, then QCC is very low.  The Epoch is 0.  As in 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but I'm gonna try guessing anyways.

So you initialized a variable `QCC` with a timestamp (say `1406204887676`).

If you now do `lastCheck = Date.now() - QCC` you get as a result the number of milliseconds that passed since `QCC` (e.g. 5000 would mean 5 seconds have passed).

I hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lastCheck = new Date().getTime() - QCC
```

Comment: Hi, just tried you suggestion and it seems to be giving the exact same results

Comment: [Date.getTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime() returns time in milliseconds.

Comment: So it does, so dividing the answer by 1000 is what i want then to get it in to seconds

Comment: new Date().getTime() and Date.now() return the same result, i.e. new Date().getTime() == Date.now().